# Why do I get a Unexpected Token?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm making a website with a sort of javascript application. I worked on it very long, but in the end it all worked. So as I was cleaning up all my code of comments, I refreshed my site and tested this application one more time, but it didn't work anymore. The error that I get says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Down here at line 13 is where the error occurs.

```
<table class="calculator" id="calculator">
        <tr>
            <th>Materiaal</th>
            <th>Waarde(&euro;/kg)</th>
            <th>Hoeveelheid(kg)</th>
            <th>Subtotaal</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IJzer</td>
            <td>0,15</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" min="0" id="ironinput" onchange=calculator( "iron") onkeyup=calculator( "iron") value=0>
            </td> <!--This is where the error occurs-->
            <td id="ironoutput">0.00</td>
        </tr>
```

This is my javascript:

```js
var materials = ["iron", "copper", "aluminum"];

var iron = 0.15;
var copper = 4.00;
var aluminum = 0.70;

function calculator(material) {
    var input = document.getElementById(material + "input").value;

    switch (material) {
        case "iron":
            document.getElementById(material + "output").innerHTML = (input * iron).toFixed(2);
            break;
        case "copper":
            document.getElementById(material + "output").innerHTML = (input * copper).toFixed(2);
            break;
        case "aluminum":
            document.getElementById(material + "output").innerHTML = (input * aluminum).toFixed(2);
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = getTotal().toFixed(2);
};

function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++ ) {
        total += Number(document.getElementById(materials[i] + "output").innerHTML);
    }
    return total;
};
```

I hope someone can help me, I'm a beginner at web development so I hope I can get a relativily easy solution and a explanation why this happens. Thank you guys.

Comment: The error is not occurring in your HTML...it is in your javascript file. Can you highlight what your line 13 of that js file is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your event attributes:

```
<input type="number" min="0" id="ironinput" onchange="calculator('iron');" onkeyup="calculator('iron');" value="0" />
```

Functions don't have to end with a semicolon:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
```

Function expressions do (avoid side effects):

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log('foo');
};
```

You also don't need both the `keyup` and the `change` events.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wtwx8vbj/

Answer (score 0):

You probably should enclose your onchange and onkeyup attributes in quotes:

```
<input type="number" min="0" id="ironinput" onchange="calculator('iron')" onkeyup="calculator('iron')" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<input onchange=calculator( "iron") >
```

is wrong, bad HTML attribute definition. Attribute value has to be enclosed in brackets if it is not a NMTOKEN, so:

```
<input onchange='calculator( "iron")' >
```

Check https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attributes